# When does engine lugging occur

Tags: engine, rpm, torque

Recently I was driving on the autobahn in my 2011 Audi A4 TDi with stage 1 tune to 177 HP / 390 Nm.

Typically I would be in 6th gear from 90 km/t and above, leaving the RPM quite low. This is unless I was travelling uphill, in which I would be going 5th instead.

Accelerating from this point in a level environment had me push the throttle a little while accelerating to around 110 km/t, where I'd increase it a little more to 120 km/t, and after passing 2,000 RPM I would increase it further.

During one of the hillclimbs, (hard to say how steep), I was around 2,500 RPM in 6th gear, travelling around 160-170 km/t. I would keep the throttle nearly wide open from then, and although a little slow, the car would continue to climb in speed. Is this considered lugging, or is it fine for the engine given the rpm and the fact it was climbing?

My car starts redline at 4,500 RPM and the limiter kicks in at 5,000

Comment: I don't know if you can consider what a diesel engine does as lugging.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 please enlighten me, what do you mean?

Comment: It depends on both the power and torque curves , which as you have altered the car you will need to produce from a dynamometer test.

Comment: @SolarMike got them right [here](http://imgur.com/a/CK6MD), blue is horsepower, red is torque

Comment: It would be hard to explain ... it all has to do with how the diesel engine runs and ignites the air/fuel mixture. I'm sitting here thinking about how to explain and it's eluding me at present.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I see. Take your time, I deeply appreciate your help!

Comment: So, below roughly 1200 rpm and you will probably class as lugging if the hill is significant - 1500 and you start to get towards max torque so it will pull well but may not accelerate. But 2000 and up she should accelerate very well! Of course you should be able to "feel" all this as you drive it- these are "best guess" from the info...

Comment: @SolarMike seems like I was will within the boundaries of the engine, then. I would be easy on the throttle until I passed 2,000 rpm, then I'd give it quite some throttle but not go completely full until roughly 2,800 and above. I could not hear any engine sound at that point, only the turbo whistle and the wind. It did not feel like I was lugging it, but accelerating 1.8 tons uphill at 160 km/h and above requires some energy. Judging by your statement on 1200 rpm, does it mean that you will probably not be lugging the engine if it is producing sufficient torque?

Comment: As I said best guess, but at 1200 the power is low but the torque significant - may hold speed but not accelerate - you have to "feel" what she is telling you

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah. Wasn't near 1,200 when pushing the engine, and the car definitely was accelerating in that uphill but not lightning fast. Hard to judge how fast it accelerates without looking too much on the speedometer when you're moving at such high speeds. The feel would probably be similar to what you experience close to maximum speed of a vehicle (level road) - where full throttle doesn't accelerate the car very fast, but you're keeping the throttle at max.

Comment: I've yet to see clear definition of what lugging is or a satisfactory reason why it's harmful to an engine. I'm eager to see this answer.

Comment: @Mysterfxit stand by you on that one. Though it's only speculation on my part, it seems to me you're putting maximum load on the engine to move the pistons faster but they're unable due to excess load / weight. As a result, all this energy is instead used to shake the engine and take a toll on pistons / conrods / bearings

Comment: 2500 rpm in sixth gear is lugging under hard acceleration, when you have no or little acceleration under hard acceleration you are lugging the engine no matter what the gear.

Comment: @Moab I was not going full throttle until I passed 3,000 if I recall correctly. I would never floor the car if I felt the car wouldn't react to it by accelerating. It definitely did accelerate, but the car had to work hard accelerating that weight to 200 km/t uphill and hence you didn't have a "launch" feel. The power curve approaches maximum power at 2,500-3,000 and downshifting at 3,000 would land me at redline or very close, making the engine lose power rapidly as the curve falls dramatically past 4,500.